# UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal animation duration?

Tags: ios, animation, uikit, duration, uimodaltransitionstyle

What is the default value of `(NSTimeInterval)duration` for `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`, which is related to `-[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]`?

Comment: [NSTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) is a double (typedef) which specifies the number of seconds the animation should last.  Other than that I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking what the default value of the duration is on an animation when you do not explicitly set it, the answer is provided in the framework headers:

> ```
>  * If the `duration' property of the animation is zero or negative it
>  * is given the default duration, either the value of the
>  * `animationDuration' transaction property or .25 seconds otherwise.
> ```

So, since you can't set the value on the method call, it should take a quarter second to execute the animation.

Comment: Thanks. I actually think, judging by eye, that it's more like `0.75` for `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`.

Comment: I agree.  I was surprised to find this in the header.  I'm wondering if it is chaining 3 animations together to get the final effect.